# Show that $a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \cos (\theta - \varphi)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Show that:

\begin{align*}
  a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \cos (\theta - \varphi)
\end{align*}

fyi, the context is in studying the differential equation:

\begin{align*}
  y''(t) + c^2 y(t) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

which has general solution:

\begin{align*}
  y(t) &= a \cos (ct) + b \sin (ct) \\
\end{align*}

My textbook says that this can easily be transformed into, where $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$:

\begin{align*}
  y(t) &= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \cos (ct - \varphi) \\
\end{align*}

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor

Comment: Or less glibly, if $a \cos \theta = \Re(a e^{i \theta})$ and $b \sin \theta = \Re(a e^{i \theta - i \pi/2})$, then $a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta = \Re( (a + b e^{-i \pi/2}) e^{i \theta})$; play with this until you get something of the correct form.

Comment: Hint: $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ are always 90° out of phase. Think about what this might mean in terms of a rotating right triangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [compound-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)
$$\cos(\theta-\varphi)=\cos\varphi\cos\theta+\sin\varphi\sin\theta.$$

To solve
$$\cos\varphi=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\,\sin\varphi=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
[take](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)$$\varphi=\operatorname{atan2}\left(b,\,a\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the vector $v = (a, b)$. The inner product of $v$ with the unit vector
$u = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ satisfies:
$$
a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta = v \cdot u = ||v|| \cdot ||u|| \cdot \cos \beta,
$$
where $\beta$ is the angle between $v$ and $u$. Define $\varphi := \theta - \beta$.